# How is GNFS the best factoring algorithm when its time complexity exceeds brute-force?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, factoring, computational-complexity

While researching another problem, the Sieve of Eratosthenes got me wondering why it couldn’t be used to factor. After playing around, I stumbled upon an algorithm that seems like it should find factors in $O(n^2)$ time — admittedly brute-force, but still in polynomial time. Meanwhile, the [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) is currently used to factor the largest numbers, but its time complexity is abysmal, or at least too complicated to get a good sense of what it’s doing just from looking at the notation.

What I came up with is this: for any number $n$, we know all non-trivial factors $f$ (if they exist) must satisfy $1 < f < \frac{n}{2}$. Therefore, for each integer $1 < i < \frac{n}{2}$, if $n \bmod i = 0$, $i$ is a factor of $n$. We can calculate this via counting by $i$ up to $\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2}$ times. Counting by $i$ requires $i$ steps, so to reach $\frac{n}{2}$ requires $\frac{n}{2}$ steps. Doing this for every $i$ between 2 and $n/2$ requires $\frac{n}{2} - 1$ iterations.

If I’m doing my math right, $\frac{n}{2}$ steps $\times \frac{n}{2} - 1$ iterations equals $\frac{n^2}{4} - \frac{n}{2}$ total steps, which simplifies to a time complexity of $O(n^2)$, and the computer memory required should be something like $O(n \log n)$, since we don’t need to keep all the intermediate results, just the factors we generate.

So in what sense is the GNFS better than this — what am I missing?

Comment: You may also consider posting these kinds of questions at https://cs.stackexchange.com/ in the future (since you can get other perspectives from CS folks)

Comment: There's some relevant discussion/terminology [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/50768/76272) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19647658). A side note is that simple trial division works perfectly well to prime factorise $n$ in $O(\sqrt n)$ arithmetic operations (so if you're using long division, the actual time is $O(\sqrt n \log^2 n)$). But this is still only pseudopolynomial and not polynomial time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your algorithm is $O(N^2)$ in the number $N$ we're factoring. But when we talk about complexity of algorithms, we measure with respect to the size of the input, NOT with respect to the size of what the input represents!

For example, if we want to give $32$ to our algorithm, the actual input it receives is (in binary) $100000$, which is of size $6$. NOT of size $32$. If we want to give even $127$ to our algorithm, the actual input is $1111111$, which is of size $7$.

In general, to represent $N$, we need $\approx \log_2(N)$ many bits. Said another way, an input of size $n$ can represent numbers as large as $N = 2^n$. So an $O(N^2)$ algorithm is actually $O((2^n)^2) = O(2^{2n})$ in the size of the *input*, and thus is exponentially slow.

Meanwhile, the GNFS algorithm runs in time $\approx$

$$\tilde{O} \left ( 2^{C \log(N)^{1/3}} \right ) = \tilde{O} \left ( 2^{ C n^{1/3} } \right )$$

(where the $\tilde{O}$ notation means I'm suppressing some lower order terms from the big O). Of course,

$$2^{Cn^{1/3}} \ll 2^{2n}$$

so that the GNFS algorithm really is asymptotically faster. In fact, $2^{n^{1/3}}$ grows *subexponentially* in $n$ (but still superpolynomially) so that it's better than any algorithm that's polynomial time in $N = 2^n$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Note that you rarely see such detailed computations because for most practical purposes number-related inputs are fixed size (int32/int64 or whatever sensible word-size in your computer), but quickly becomes relevant when you get into  *really big numbers* where cost of *operating* on numbers grows along with numbers themselves.  Like precise `n!` has just O(n) multiplication operations, but total time cost must take into account the fact 1! *2  multiplication is cheaper than "100000! * 100001" even if it the same operation.

Comment: This convention is not consistently followed. For instance, naive matrix multiplication of two $n \times n$ matrices is always stated to have complexity $O(n^3)$. This is a size with respect to what the input represents, not the size of the input.